# How do I implement a Antlr4 parser that resolve ambiguity when both rules use "=="?

Tags: javascript, antlr4, lexer

I know the title is not clear enough. Here is the details. I need to parse something like below:

```js
Client->iFrame.Initialise() {
  res = Server.loadStaticResource()
  if (res.status == 404 || res.status == 503) {  <1>
     throw Error()
  }
}
== Initialisation done! ==                       <2>
Client->iFrame.load(data) {
   moreStatements()
}
```

It is a Java-like syntax, except that we support a Divider (shown as `== Initialisation done! ==` in the example). Note that:

1. both <1> and <2> uses `==`.
2. It is treated as a Divider only if it appears at the beginning of the line (after spaces removed).
3. Any character can be used between the starting `==` and ending `==` except for changelines.
4. There could be more `=` in the Divider component, such as `=== 3 equals ===`.

How should I implement that?

To add more context, this is to be used to render a sequence diagram like below. It is an opensource project and can be found here: https://github.com/ZenUml/core

[image: sequence diagram for divider]

What I have tried?

I was looking for a way to use lookahead in the Lexer, but could not find any good examples. I am currently limiting the content between starting `==` and ending `==` to ONE word only.

My implementation is here:

1. The parser: https://github.com/ZenUml/core/blob/b84c9ca0a6d023c5e520bf83a225e4931db134fc/src/g4/sequenceParser.g4#L88-L89
2. The lexer: https://github.com/ZenUml/core/blob/main/src/g4/sequenceLexer.g4

Comment: Anyway if newlines have semantic significance, then you know that the start of a line is a new statement (or whatever you want to call it). Like JavaScript, the first token of a statement can tell you what non-terminal you want to parse.

Comment: A newline is only semantically in this case. In all other cases, it is not. For example, `A.method() { B.method() } ` they can be in one line. I am not sure if I am thinking in the right direction, but I am trying to use a look-backward to match `==` for divider only if it the beginning of a newline.

Comment: Hmm. Well, and obviously I have not thought deeply about this, but it definitely reminds me of the weirdness in JavaScript about "automatic semicolon insertion".

Comment: OK first, I don't know where the comments are going. That's weird, just to get that out of the way. Now, as to the parsing issues, I'm not super-familiar with Antlr, but in my parsing endeavors I've always tried to be pragmatic about what's easy to do in the lexer vs. what's easy to do in the parser. For example (and this may be wrong for you), consider a "\n==" token that the lexer could recognize.

Comment: A really long time ago I had to write a Pascal parser, and there's a difficulty with the notation for "range" types that look like `1..10` because they overlap with floating-point constants. So me and a friend came up with the idea of the lexer having an "integer dot dot" token, which made the parser difficulty go away.

Comment: The easiest solution is to assume '==' starts in column 0 and set the lexer in a new mode. Something like this: Lexer (C# target, adjust for JS target): `EQZ : { this.Column == 0 }? '==' -> pushMode(Eqz); EQ : '=='; ... mode Eqz; Stuff : [ \ta-zA-Z_!][a-zA-Z_0-9!]* -> type(ID); End : '==' -> popMode, type(EQZ);` Parser: `divider : EQZ name* EQZ ;`. You'll have to do '=' counting. (Tested, works.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here's the answer evolved from the question and comments, and from my experience writing little parsers for a long time.

Rule 1: find a way to cheat

In the case of ambiguities like in this question, looking for a solution in the lexer can be a useful avenue to explore. In this case, because newlines apparently have some degree of meaning, introducing a token that matches a newline followed by a couple of `=` signs means that the *parser* sees a token ("newline equal equal") that directly indicates the start of that production.

The particular "cheat" is a `\n==` token, so that the grammar can have that as a separator or statement start (whatever makes sense). If it appears at a weird point in the grammar somehow, the parser can throw an error that says "unexpected start of the == thing" because it knows that's what's going on.